# iOS - View Controller memory management when doing async networking calls with success block

Tags: ios, memory-management, asynchronous, uiviewcontroller, objective-c-blocks

Is there anything wrong with this code?

```
[[MyNetworkManager shared] getSomeData:param success:^(NSDictionary *response) { 
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
} failure:^(NSString *errorString) {

}];
```

Specifically, if the view controller that calls this method gets deallocated before the network task completes, what happens? Is weakSelf, strongSelf required here? Why or why not?

The network manager just makes a network call and returns the response to the calling view controller by doing this if it gets valid data from the server:

```
success(dictionary);
```

It seems fine to me because the block itself is not retained anywhere, but I could be wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of `self` here will prevent the view controller from being deallocated until after the network request is done. There is nothing here that would suggest that you need to do that in this case, so the use of `self` seems inappropriate here. We can fabricate scenarios where you might need the view controller to be retained (but the scenarios also suggest a certain degree of code smell).

You can use the `weakSelf` pattern here, and this won't maintain a strong reference on the view controller. Thus, if the view controller is dismissed before the network request is done, it will be deallocated and the `weakSelf` pointer will be `nil`. This seems to be a logical approach here.

You do not need to use the `weakSelf`/`strongSelf` pattern, though. You use that if you need to ensure that if the pointer is not `nil` when the block starts, that it won't become `nil` during the execution of the block. That's not applicable to this example.

So, that means that you'd probably have something like:

```
typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;

[[MyNetworkManager shared] getSomeData:param success:^(NSDictionary *response) { 
    weakSelf.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
} failure:^(NSString *errorString) {

}];
```

---

Note, you have to ask yourself whether you really need the query to continue to run after the view controller is deallocated. If not, you might make this request cancelable, and then cancel it once the view is dismissed. But that's a separate topic altogether.

Comment: "The use of self here will prevent the view controller from being deallocated until after the network request is done." Why is that? What is retaining the view controller?

Comment: Blocks maintain strong reference to any objects captured within the block unless the object reference is `weak` (or, much worse, `__unsafe_unretained`). So, if you reference `self`, it maintains strong reference to `self` until the block is released. See the _Object and Block Variables_ section of [Blocks Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html).